# How could I know if I already import a modul and reload it if it has been modified?

Tags: python, class, import, reload

I made a class where I have a model in it. I also made a QT GUI which allows me to select the file (.py) of my class model in order to import it and use it.
What I'm seeking for is a way to know if I already import a modul (corresponding to the file I selected) and reload it if it has changed.

to import my module from a path, i use:

```
    fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Open Data File" , "", "data files (*.py)")
    if fileName[0]=='':
        return
    fileName = str(fileName[0])
    abspath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))  
    self.fileName = os.path.relpath(fileName,abspath) 
    (filepath, filename) = os.path.split(fileName)
    sys.path.append(filepath)
    (shortname, extension) = os.path.splitext(filename)
    mod = __import__(shortname)
```

instead of `mod = __import__(shortname)` I need to make a test to know if I import or reload the module.

### EDIT

```
    if shortname not in sys.modules:
        mod = __import__(shortname)
    else:
        importlib.reload(__import__(shortname))
```

I try the previous code. however I still have an issue. when I do `importlib.reload(__import__(shortname))`, I seem that when I modify the module in between the first import and the second one, I still load the first form of the class. I added `self.A=0` in the class `__init__` but I don't have the acces to it.

Comment: There is `sys.modules`

Comment: it doesn't work when I try `mod in sys.modules`

Comment: This is generally something you want to avoid, because there are many caveats and it makes it difficult to reason about the internal state of your program.  That said, are you aware of [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload)?

Comment: Why this is something I should avoid? The reason why I do this is mainly because I'm still doing the prototyping of the model classes. So, to avoid closing my interface, I would like to be able to modify my module and reload it without closing completly  the GUI.